# File uploading does not work in IE 8

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a php application to upload excel file. It works in all browsers except IE.
Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnUpload", function() {
    var value =$("#FileUpload").val();
    if (value!=null && value!="") {
        var file_data = $("#FileUpload").prop("files")[0]; 
        var extension = value.substr( (value.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
    if(extension=='xlsx'||extension=='xls'||extension=='csv') {
        $.ajax({
        ----
        });
    }
}});
```

when I run this in IE, it shows the error `'prop(...).0' is null or not an object`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `var file = $("#FileUpload")[0].files[0]` instead of `$("#FileUpload").prop()`

Comment: how to use attr ?  var file_data = $("#FileUpload").attr("files")[0]

Comment: <input type="file" value="UploadFile" id="FileUpload"  />

Comment: @Sherin Better way is to use `$("#FileUpload")[0].files[0]`

Comment: I tried it alreay . It works in other browsers,but in IE it shows '0.files.0' is null or not an object

Comment: Ok, I see. IE8 doesn't support multiply files by design. You can at least get the filename via e.target.value